# Objective C - Error duplicate symbols - How can I add twice frameworks of google ADS?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, ads, duplicate-data, ios-frameworks

I have a problem, I need to add two different frameworks of Google ADS.

'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0' - I used it for Banners in DFP

@import GoogleMobileAds;

'GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.0.beta.14' - I used it for pre roll on videos.

@import GoogleInteractiveMediaAds;

When I use only one that framework works fine, but just the functions with this framework the other one does not work.

So, when I add these two frameworks (cocoa pods), I get this error.

[image: ERROR duplicate - Frameworks Google]

Answer (score 0):

This is solved using GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK-For-AdMob instead of GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK.

greetings

Comment: But this is deprecated.  https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleAds-IMA-iOS-SDK-For-AdMob